# Hasse diagrams and total order

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I got this question on a test and I did not know how to approach it.

If n is any positive natural, we can look at the set of naturals that divide n and consider the division partial order restricted to these numbers.

For example, here is the partial order of the divisors of 120, under division:

[image]

R is total if for any two elements x and y, R(x, y) or R(y, x).

What is the smallest positive natural n such that the partial order of divisors of n, under division, is not a total order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $m \nmid m'$ holds iff there is a prime power $p^k$ such that $p^k \mid m$, but $p^k \nmid m'$. So if $m \nmid m'$ and $m' \nmid m$ there are prime powers $p^k$ and $q^l$ such that $p^k \mid m'$, $q^l \mid m$, $p^k \nmid m$, $q^l\nmid m'$. Note that we must have $p \ne q$, hence if $n$ is a multiple of both $m$ and $m'$ we have $p^kq^l \mid n$. If we want $n$ to be smallest with these properties, we choose $p^k = 2^1$, $q^l = 3^1$ and $n = pq = 6$.

And, indeed, the divisors of 6, $T_6 = \{1,2,3,6\}$ have a diamond shaped Hasse diagram and do not form a total order.

Comment: I am trying to follow your post but it's a bit dense for me. I understand the prime powers, but 6 is your solution to it?

Comment: Yes, the solution is $6$. As $2$ and $3$ are the smallest prime powers, and $6$ is their product, the smallest number having distinct prime powers as divisors.

Comment: Oh I get it now.